# How to Pair Generators in the Presentation of Fundamental Group of a Surface

Tags: algebraic-topology

The fundamental group of a surface with genus $g$ is widely given by the group presentation (for example Hatcher p.51):

$$\langle  a(1),b(1),a(2),b(2),..,a(g),b(g) \mid  [a(1),b(1)][a(2),b(2)]...[a(g),b(g)] \rangle$$

However, as stated, the fundamental group appears to be imperfectly defined in the general case.  Specifically, the $a$-$b$ pairing is not defined.  Given the generators, one cannot use the formula without knowing how to pair them.

In other words, suppose I know the generators of a complex surface, which I arbitrarily label as $1,2,3,...,2g $.   I still cannot get the fundamental group without knowing which generators are to be paired to construct the relation.

For genus $g$ surfaces, what is the algorithm/logic for pairing the generators in the presentation of the fundamental group?

Comment: In what sense do you know the generators? Do you just know they generate the group? Do you know what the surface looks like? Do you have representatives for each of their homotopy classes?

Comment: If you have a presentation, then you can construct a surface for it. If you have a surface, you can construct a presentation. If you only have a formal list of elements without other information, its not enough information to nail down which presentation fits the given surface (though all presentations yield homeomorphic surfaces).

Comment: If you are able to compute with them in the group, then you can in principal find the relation by computing all the length 4g commutator relations and finding which ones evaluate as the identity.

Comment: @J. David.  My question is very general. The formula is imprecise since it relies on an undefined pairing of generators.  Obviously to use the formula to get the F Goup you have to use the correct pairing; but the correct pairing is never given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On page 51 of Hatcher, it is assumed that we start with an orientable surface $M_g$ of genus $g$ and have its cell structure. The cell structure contains the information of not only the cells, but how they fit together - this data is contained in the gluing maps. Since the 1-skeleton is a wedge sum of $2g$ circles, almost all of the information is included in the map gluing the 2-cell to the 1-skeleton. In particular, the boundary of the 2-cell is divided into $4g$ arcs that are identified in pairs. Each (oriented) pair is a generator of the fundamental group (by identifying it with the 1-cell it glues to) and the gluing order is the commutator relation. If you draw a square for the torus and an octagon for a genus 2 surface and work out the details, then you will see that the cell complex structure dictates the fundamental group presentation up to rotations of the 2-cell (treating it like a disc) by integral multiples of $\frac{2\pi}{4g}$ and possibly a reflection (i.e. a dihedral group).

**How the pairing is in the gluing maps** Given a arc $A_1$ of the 2-cell $D$, the gluing map $G$ identifies the arc with a 1-cell $I$. On the other hand, there is another arc $A_2$ of the 2-cell that is also identified with $I$ via $G$. This is because we are *by hypothesis* working with the cell complex structure of a orientable surface. Our hypothesis doesn't include the specifics of which cell complex we are working with beyond that, and as such we have no more information. In the concrete situation of working with an actual cell complex of an orientable surface then you can look at the map $G$ and see where it sends the boundary of $D$.

Comment: In any specific example that we can visualize, I see how it all works.  However, in the general case, the 1-skeleton is just a bunch loops connected at the basepoint, with no clear pairing.  How, exactly, are the 4g arcs "identified in pairs"?  (The only possible answer I can see is to create the homomorphism to a g-torus, and work from there.)

Comment: As I said in my post, the pairing information is not in the 1-skeleton, it is in the gluing maps. A cell complex is not just a collection of cells. It is also the information of how to arrange them. What I am reading from your statements is "The cells don't dictate how to arrange them. This is an issue." My response, in short is "Yes. The cells alone do not. But the cell structure (complex) does."